# How to store data read from Excel with SAX into HashMap and share with other class

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, hashmap, singleton, sax

I've been using Spring and java ee and I have to store information into `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>` so to share this structure with other class.
One class put information and others classes get data.
What is the best way to di it?
I need to use this data for each user on my web site, I thought to use singleton, is it good?

```
@Singleton
public class ExcelFields {
    //data structure used to store cell coordinates and value where cell coordinates are the keys
    private HashMap<String,Object> firstRowValues;
    private HashMap<String,Object> secondRowValues;
    private HashMap<String,Object> thirdRowValues;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> rowValues;
    private static ExcelFields instance = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.firstRowValues=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        this.secondRowValues=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        this.thirdRowValues=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        this.rowValues=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    }
    /**
     * @return the firstRowValues
     */
    public HashMap<String, Object> getFirstRowValues() {
        return firstRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstRowValues the firstRowValues to set
     */
    public void setFirstRowValues(HashMap<String, Object> firstRowValues) {
        this.firstRowValues = firstRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @return the secondRowValues
     */
    public HashMap<String, Object> getSecondRowValues() {
        return secondRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @param secondRowValues the secondRowValues to set
     */
    public void setSecondRowValues(HashMap<String, Object> secondRowValues) {
        this.secondRowValues = secondRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @return the thirdRowValues
     */
    public HashMap<String, Object> getThirdRowValues() {
        return thirdRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @param thirdRowValues the thirdRowValues to set
     */
    public void setThirdRowValues(HashMap<String, Object> thirdRowValues) {
        this.thirdRowValues = thirdRowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @return the rowValues
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getRowValues() {
        return rowValues;
    }
    /**
     * @param rowValues the rowValues to set
     */
    public void setRowValues(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> rowValues) {
        this.rowValues = rowValues;
    }

    public void addRowValues(HashMap<String, Object> rowValues2){
        this.rowValues.add(rowValues2);
    }

    public void clearAll(){
        firstRowValues.clear();
        secondRowValues.clear();
        thirdRowValues.clear();
        rowValues.clear();
    }



}
```

This is the use case: user uploaded excel file- I read this file and I map it into HashMap- I use this information to fill database, then I can clear HashMap for future upload (might be a lot of user simultaneous)
This is the method in Service class that call Excel read:

```
private void processSheet(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream) throws Exception {
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
        SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        ContentHandler handler = new MyXSSFSheetHandler(styles, strings);
        sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
        sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
    }
```

How you can see MyXSSFSheetHandler returns ContentHandler so I can't return HashMap.
Furthermore the HashMap has to be used into DatabaseServicesImpl Services that uses HashMap values to store into database

UPDATE: I tried to use HashMAp in MyXSSFSheetHandler adding get method, but when I call it the map is empty, it the same code of [this:http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/08/java-sax-parser-example-code-part-2.html](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/08/java-sax-parser-example-code-part-2.html)

Comment: And when you stop the application, everything is lost? Are you sure you don't want to store that in a database?

Comment: yes, this is the flow: user uploaded excel file- I read this file and I map it into HashMap- I use this information to fill database, then I can clear HashMap for future upload (might be a lot of user simultaneous)

Comment: Then it has no reason to be stored in any Map other than a local variable of a method: the upload method create a hashmap, fills it, then updates the database. No need for a globally accessible HashMap.

Comment: there is a method that read from excel(about 1500 rows and several columns) and store into hashmap(where I save coordinates and values) and there is another class that prepares database query getting informations from HashMap. I'm using Spring MVC and I would to separate database query from other class(my controller calls services that uses database class to store information)

Comment: So, create the HashMap and populate it in the first method. Then pass this HashMap as argument to the method of the second class.

Comment: I have added futher information in first post, I can't use return type

Answer (score 0):

If you want that data on next every deployment save data in .properties file and access it.

Comment: it is impossible to store into other file because I have a lot of data into Excel file

Comment: means you initialize this data on every deployment ? if excel file changes outside then how this synchronize?

Comment: I have added use case in first post, the Excel file is uploaded from one user and I have to map into database